# Solving a PDE problem involving three function in 3 variables

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I need to find $f(x,y,z), g(x,y,z), h(x,y,z)$ such that

$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2xy^2 , \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0 ,\frac{\partial h}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}=z$$

I tryied to integrate and to do the usual but I came out with a lot of new functions and I dont have an idea of how to manage them, any easy idea to solve it?

Comment: You solve it exactly as you said you did it, as you stated you just need to keep track of the new functions that arise from integration. Or note that the problem can be written as $$\nabla \times \vec{f} = \vec{b}$$ with $\vec{f} = (f, g, h), \vec{b} = (z, 0, 2xy^{2})$ and so there is a homogeneous solution $\vec{f}_{h} = \nabla \varphi$ and then a particular solution which, as before, still needs to be determined via integration.